# On click, it changes the color of one container on ListViewBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application that displays news. I want when clicking on the title of the news, the color of the container always changes and does not return with the second click or when the application is closed, in order for the user to distinguish that this news has been read, but I encountered two problems. Containers return to their default color when navigating to and from the page.

````
Color _colorContainer = Colors.blue;
 ListView.builder(
                    
                    itemCount: snapshot.docs.length 
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) 
                        return  InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                  _colorContainer = Colors.red ;
                });
                                           }
                         child: Container(
                           color:  _colorContainer,
                          child: Text('news title'),
                        ); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

to achieve what you want you must store somewhere the status of those containers not at run time because when you exit that view and re-enter the status will be as unread in this particular case
Look this example to local storage:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

https://pub.dev/packages/hive

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences